# Getting keyboard input doesn't work for arrow keys

Tags: python, windows, input, key, msvcrt

I want to check what key was pressed while waiting for the input, just like with `getch()`.

I tried:

```
from msvcrt import getch
ch = ord(getch())
```

and

```
import readchar
ch = readchar.readkey()
ch = readchar.readchar()
```

and then I'm printing `ch` to see what's underneath.

```
print(ch)
```

Works fine for letters, but for Arrow keys it always returns the same value no matter the key:

for `ord(getch())` it's `224`
for `readchar.readkey()` it's `None`
and for `readchar.readchar()` it's `b'\xe0'`

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Python 3.8 if that matters.

Any way to fix it, do it while making it work like `getch()`? (Waiting for input)

Comment: maybe you should use models like `pynput` or `keyboard`

Comment: did you try it without `Visual Studio`? `Visual Studio` may catch keys and send only chars to program.

Comment: I tried readchar.readkey() on replit, it prints nothing

Comment: `replit` can use fake console which may not send it - test it on real console/terminal

Comment: ` ch = getch().upper()

    if ch in [b'\x00', b'\xe0']:
        ch = getch()

        ch = ch.decode('utf-8') ` this works fine for me, will give a letter for each arrow key

Comment: I tested only `ch = readchar.readkey()` and `print(repr(ch))` on LInux and it works for me - I get `'\x1b[A'` for `UP`, `'\x1b[B'` for `DOWN`, etc. Some keys have codes bigger than 255 so they need 2 bytes - but `getch()` reads only one byte and it may need to run it second time.

Comment: When an arrow or function key is pressed there is a leading prefix value of `'\x00` or `\xe0` and you have to call `getch()` *again* to get the actual key pressed. This is in the `getch()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch).

Answer (score 0):

when you run `getch()` the first time and you click on any arrow it will return  `b'\xe0'` but when
you run `getch()` the second time it will return  `b'H'` or `b'P'` or `b'K'` or `b'M'`

```
def read_keys():
        while True:
            key = getch()
            if (key == b'\x00' or key ==b'\xe0'):
                key = getch()
                print('Arrow key', ord(key))
            else:
                print("Else", ord(key))

read_keys()
```